# Laravel failed to run command "php artisan key:generate" in any docker with GitLab

Tags: laravel-5, gitlab, laravel-5.3, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I use GitLab CI to run test a Laravel app.

It always get issue at command `php artisan key:generate`:

[image]

> Warning: require(/builds/anhduc-bkhn/laravel-gitlab-example/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /builds/anhduc-bkhn/laravel-gitlab-example/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/builds/anhduc-bkhn/laravel-gitlab-example/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /builds/anhduc-bkhn/laravel-gitlab-example/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I fixed it. The reason is git ignores vendor/ folder.

Comment: It's supposed to ignore it, maybe you should run composer first?

Comment: @JakubKania I use docker to run it, already commit composer's dependencies.
It already work now, thank for your comment

Comment: Well, it's your workflow but you should only commit composer.json and composer.lock and install the rest with composer

Comment: Yes, i knew, i dont want installing composer in server so i commit vendor/ folder